# How to retrieve all the data inside all the elements in xml?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am having an issue getting xml data in php

My xml is fairly complicated and there are several nested children in the tag.

xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<book id="5">
<title id="76">test title</title>
<figure id="77"></figure>

<ch id="id78">
<aa id="80"><emph>content1</emph></aa>
<ob id="id_84" page-num="697" extra-info="4"><emph type="bold">opportunity.</emph></ob>
<ob id="id_85" page-num="697" extra-info="5"><emph type="bold">test data.</emph></ob>
<para id="id_86" page-num="697">2008.</para>

<body>
   ..more elements
   <content>more contents..
   </content>
</body>
</ch>
```

MY codes

```
//I need to load many different xml files.

 $xml_file = simplexml_load_file($filename);
          foreach ($xml_file->children() as $child){
              echo $child->getName().':'. $child."<br>";
          }
```

The codes above would only display

`book, title, figure, ch` but not the elements inside the `ch` tag. How do I display all the element inside each tag? Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: at a minimum your `<ob>` `</objective>` tags don't match. . .

Comment: sorry, it was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to match your `<ob>` `</objective>` tags.
2. Your foreach needs to be recursive. You should check if each item in your foreach has a child, then recursively foreach over that elements. I'd recommend using a separate function for this that you recursively call.

Example:

```
$xml_file = simplexml_load_file($filename);
parseXML($xml_file->children());
function parseXML($xml_children)
{
    foreach ($xml_children as $child){
        echo $child->getName().':'. $child."<br>";
        if ($child->count() > 0)
        {
            parseXML($child->children());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error saying hasChildren is not defined...+1 though.

Comment: Try `if ($child->count() > 0)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do resursive call

```
parseAllXml($xml_file);

function parseAllXml($xmlcontent)
{
 foreach($xmlcontent->children() as $child)
   {
     echo $child->getName().':'. $child."<br>";
     $is_further_child = ( count($child->children()) >0 )?true:false;  
     if( $is_further_child )
     {
        parseAllXml($child);
     }   
 }
}
```